# Is there a text-mode equivalent of $\approx$?

Tags: text

In non-equation mode, using the normal font. How do I make the approximation sign that in mathematical mode is `$\approx$`?

Comment: Why should it be a non mathematical mode? Please, give to us an example you are using it. Maybe what you want is `$\text{foo}\approx \text{faa}$` (or simply `foo $\approx$ faa`).

Comment: unless you are using luatex or xetex the normal text fonts will not have that character. If you are, and your main font does have the character, you can just use `≈` directly.

Comment: or stack two tildes if you really want text mode: `\raisebox{-0.7ex}{\textasciitilde}\hspace{-5pt}\raisebox{-1.0ex}{\textasciitilde}` - note: not a serious suggestion, don't try this at home :)

Comment: And of course `\newcommand{\textapprox}{\hbox{$\null\approx\null$}}}`

Comment: @Sigur I thought it could be nice, just by the same reson that `=` exists both in mathematical mode and text mode. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Cool. But is that code-page-dependent? Like with the Swedish letters `åäö` that sometimes has to be written as `\r{a}\"{a}\"{o}`?

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson luatex and xetex always use UTF-8 input and TU (Unicode) font encoding so the issue does not arise but even in pdftex, you never _need_ to use `\r{a}\"{a}\"{o}` although you can if it's more convenient, you can always input the letters as åäö

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson modern OpenType fonts have tens of thousands of characters, so it's easy to find `≈` in a text font, but the original (OT1) TeX fonts had 127 characters per font, and even the extended (T1) font encodings only have 256, so there simply isn't room to add math characters other than the most basic `=+-\times`